# Three columns - get MAX with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table:

Rating:

```
id | one | two | three
1  | 12  | 3   | 7
2  | 11  | 30  | 3
3  | 8   | 14  | 4
```

How can i get with SQL MAX values from these fields (one, two, three)? For this example this is **30**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) Function:

```
SELECT  MAX(GREATEST(one, two, three))
FROM    T;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b116/4)**

Comment: The "greatest" function also exists in Oracle, so this solution works for Oracle as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT MAX(field) FROM (
    SELECT one AS field FROM table
    UNION 
    SELECT two AS field FROM table
    UNION 
    SELECT three AS field FROM table
) AS t
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select GREATEST(max(one), max(two), max(three)) as maximum 
from table;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can *unpivot* the data similar to this:

```
select max(value)
from
(
  select id, 'one' col, one value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select id, 'two' col, two value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select id, 'three' col, three value
  from yourtable
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46495/1).

Or you can use something like this:

```
SELECT max(data)
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    CASE s.col
      WHEN 'one' THEN one
      WHEN 'two' THEN two
      WHEN 'three' THEN three
    END AS DATA
  FROM yourtable t
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 'one' AS col
    UNION ALL SELECT 'two'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'three'
  ) s
) s
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46495/3)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
SELECT tempTable.id, tempTable.max(val) 
FROM (SELECT id, max(one) AS val
      FROM tbl 
      UNION 
      SELECT id, max(two) AS val
      FROM tbl 
      UNION 
      SELECT id, max(three) AS val
      FROM tbl
) AS tempTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max( if( one > two, if( one > three, one, three ), if( two > three, two, three ) )
  from Rating
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` statement

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN one >= two AND one >= three THEN one
        WHEN two >= one AND two >= three THEN two
        WHEN three >= one AND three >= two THEN three
        ELSE one
    END AS MaxVal
```